# How to pass fragment from fragment manager to viewpager inside dashboard activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I need to give horizontal swipe navigation to custom tab layout. I think this code snippet will help you to fix the issue. There are 3 fragments attached to viewpageradapter. I have declared the viewpager object of the Viewpager class but the problem still exists.

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
//    private ViewPager mViewPager;


    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Toolbar");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        TabLayout tabLayout;
        ViewPager viewPager;
        tabLayout=(TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.ViewPager);

        viewPager= new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new HomeFragment(),"HOME");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new TopPaidFragment(),"TOP PAID");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new TopFreeFragment(),"TOP FREE");

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.ViewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);




    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_dashboard, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:


                return true;

            case R.id.add_pic:

                return true;
            case R.id.Add_Story:

                return true;
            case R.id.delete:

                return true;
            case R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);


            default:`enter code here`
                // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }


}

`enter code here`layout_xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            />
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ViewPager"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="33dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus_circle"
        android:hint="@string/add_story"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post your error logs please?

Comment: viewPagerAdapter instance is null. This code throw NullPointerException. viewPager= new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set adapter object to viewpager

change this line

`viewPager= new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());`

to

`viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());`

Comment: thanks the solution worked .. but now the background color of the whole screen has been changed to tab background color

Comment: That is so, because you have placed ViewPager in your AppBarLayout, just take that out from there.